# Reading trigger data from xbox wireless controllers

Tags: bluetooth, xbox-one, hidapi

So I'm using hidapi to reading input packets from a few xbox controllers I have and one thing frustrating me is that it reports the left and right triggers as a single "rudder" axis with a `uint16_t`. Is there any sort of packet I can send to change the report structure? I know that there are games that can use both triggers at the same time. I guess that the Microsoft answer would be to use DirectInput but I would really like to be able to roll my own.

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct xbox_wireless_controller_report {
    static const u8 a = 1;
    static const u8 b = 2;
    static const u8 x = 4;
    static const u8 y = 8;
    static const u8 lb = 16;
    static const u8 rb = 32;
    static const u8 select = 64;
    static const u8 start = 128;

    static const u8 l3 = 1;
    static const u8 r3 = 2;

    u16 left_stick_x;
    u16 left_stick_y;
    u16 right_stick_x;
    u16 right_stick_y;

    u16 rudder;
    
    u8 buttons; // a, b, x, y, lb, rb, select, start
    u8 l3r3;
    u8 dpad;
    u8 unknown[2]; // just here to make 15 bytes
};

static_assert(sizeof(xbox_wireless_controller_report) == 15);
```

Comment: I found one answer here, if I change the driver from XInput to HID it now reports an entirely different packet structure. I wish there was an easier way though. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/xbox-one-controller-wireless-adapter-z-axis-and/04316052-7b19-400c-be30-6b4d30340389

Comment: FWIW: the Microsoft answer is to use XINPUT, Windows.Gaming.Input, or GameInput. Not legacy DirectInput.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the HID-driver exposed by the Xbox Common Controller have this behavior is for backcompat reasons with some older DirectInput-based racing titles.

The recommendation is to use XINPUT, Windows.Gaming.Input, or GameInput and not legacy DirectInput for the Xbox gamepads.

> There is an undocumented registry key you can use to manipulate this mapping on your system, but keep in mind that this will impact *all* use of the Xbox Common Controller via DirectInput. [How to detect gamepad triggers both pushed with USB HID API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764857/how-to-detect-gamepad-triggers-both-pushed-with-usb-hid-api)